# C Insert int and doubles inside structure

Tags: c, struct

I have a problem with a small project, I have to create a structure containing a person's data,I have to do data entry via a function using pointers.
I don't understand why when I try to enter the `weight` the program ends with this error:
`Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`
I made an example of the code that is giving me problems:

```
typedef struct{
    char name[DIM];
    char surname[DIM];
    int height;
    float weight;
    }Record;
    
int main() {
    Record subj;
    insRecord(&subj);
}
 
void insRecord(Record *subj){
    printf("\nName ");
    scanf("%64[^\n]s", subj->name);
    cleanBuffer();
    printf("\nSurname ");
    scanf("%64[^\n]s", subj->surname);
    cleanBuffer();
    printf("\nEight ");
    scanf("%3s", subj->height);
    cleanBuffer();
    printf("\nWeight ");
    scanf("%6s", subj->weight);
    cleanBuffer();
}
 
int cleanBuffer(){
    int cont= 0;
    char c;
    do{
        cont++;
        c = getchar();
    }while(c != '\n');
    return cont;
}
```

(I only wrote the main functions).

Furthermore, compiler is giving warnings on `height` and `weight` `scanf()` statements:

```
Format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'int' (for height)
Format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'double' (for weight)
```

Could you tell me how can I solve?

PS the project is divided into several files (3 files).
In `main.c` I wrote the `insRecord()` function, in `struct.h` I wrote the `Record` structure, in `struct.c` I wrote `cleanBuffer()` function.

Comment: What is the confusion with the warnings you are getting? They are very clear and pointing to a problem in your code. Fix those warnings and your program should work find. Change this `scanf("%3s", subj->height);` to this `scanf("%3d", &subj->height);` and this `scanf("%6s", subj->weight);` to this `scanf("%6f", &subj->weight);`. Read about [scanf()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading a string (%s) and try to store that in a float. If you use the flag %f for weight and %d for height it will probably work better. Remember that you should provide a pointer to the float and int that you want to store the data in, you are not doing that in your example.

Have a look at the scanf documentation:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm

Good luck